# The second owl carousel photo slider is not working

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I've been busy on this for a while, asked multiple questions here.

But here is the whole code, it's about the second carousel that won't work, the first one works great.

thanks.

http://pastebin.com/wtPgi4cV

Comment: thanks, but didn't do the trick

Answer (score 2):

To use more owl-carousel at the same time just use different "id"

### javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-demo1").owlCarousel();
  $("#owl-demo2").owlCarousel();

});
```

### html

```
<div id="owl-demo1" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img src="slide1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="slide2.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="slide3.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="slide4.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="slide5.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="slide6.jpg"></div>
</div>

<div id="owl-demo2" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img src="slide7.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="slide8.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="slide9.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="slide10.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="slide11.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="slide12.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i've got that, don't i?

Comment: sorry still not working.. do i need to change anything at the data-target?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="crousel-set">
    <div class="item"><img src="slide1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="slide2.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="slide3.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="slide4.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="slide5.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="slide6.jpg"></div>
</div>

<div class="crousel-set">
    <div class="item"><img src="slide7.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="slide8.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="slide9.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="slide10.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="slide11.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="slide12.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".crousel-set").each(function(index, crousel) {
        crousel.owlCarousel();
    });
});
```